# Merging list of tuples in scala based on key

Tags: scala

I have a list of tuples look like this:

```
Seq("ptxt"->"how","list"->"you doing","ptxt"->"whats up","ptxt"-> "this ","list"->"is ","list"->"cool")
```

On the keys, merge *ptxt* with all the list that will come after it.
e.g.
create a new seq look like this :

```
Seq("how you doing", "whats up", "this is cool")
```

Comment: Did you mess up your keys in the question? Why would e.g. "ptxt" value "this" be merged with "list" values "is" and "cool"?

Comment: because each "ptxt" can have zero to N values

Answer (score 7):

You could *fold* your `Seq` with `foldLeft`:

```scala
val s = Seq("ptxt"->"how ","list"->"you doing","ptxt"->"whats up","ptxt"-> "this ","list"->"is ","list"->"cool")

val r: Seq[String] = s.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
  case (xs, ("ptxt", s)) => s :: xs
  case (x :: xs, ("list", s)) => (x + s) :: xs
}.reverse
```

If you don't care about an order you can omit `reverse`.

---

Function `foldLeft` takes two arguments first is the initial value and the second one is a function taking two arguments: the previous result and element of the sequence. Result of this method is then fed the next function call as the first argument.

For example for numbers `foldLeft`, would just create a sum of all elements starting from left.

```
List(5, 4, 8, 6, 2).foldLeft(0) { (result, i) =>
  result + i
} // 25
```

For our case, we start with an empty list. Then we provide function, which handles two cases using pattern matching.

- Case when the key is "ptxt". In this case, we just prepend the value to list.

  ```
  case (xs, ("ptxt", s)) => s :: xs
  ```
- Case when the key is "list". Here we take the first string from the list (using pattern matching) and then concatenate value to it, after that we put it back with the rest of the list.

  ```
  case (x :: xs, ("list", s)) => (x + s) :: xs
  ```

At the end since we were prepending element, we need to revert our list. Why we were prepending, not appending? Because append on the immutable list is `O(n)` and prepend is `O(1)`, so it's more efficient.

Comment: This is so cool, it working!!!, I am new to scala can you please explain how dose it work?

Comment: @MichaelBiniashvili Added some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Here another solution:

```
val data = Seq("ptxt"->"how","list"->"you doing","ptxt"->"whats", "list" -> "up","ptxt"-> "this ", "list"->"is cool")
```

First group Keys and Values:

```
val grouped = s.groupBy(_._1)
               .map{case (k, l) => k -> l.map{case (_, v) => v.trim}}

// > Map(list -> List(you doing, up, is cool), ptxt -> List(how, whats, this))
```

Then zip and concatenate the two values:

```
grouped("ptxt").zip(grouped("list"))
    .map{case (a, b) => s"$a $b"}

// > List(how you doing, whats up, this is cool)
```

**Disclaimer**: This only works if the there is always `key, value, key, value,..` in the list - I had to adjust the input data.

Answer (score 2):

If you change `Seq` for `List`, you can solve that with a simple **tail-recursive** function.
*(The code uses Scala 2.13, but can be rewritten to use older Scala versions if needed)*

```
def mergeByKey[K](list: List[(K, String)]): List[String] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[(K, String)], acc: Map[K, StringBuilder]): List[String] =
    remaining match {
      case Nil =>
        acc.valuesIterator.map(_.result()).toList

      case (key, value) :: tail =>
        loop(
          remaining = tail,
          acc.updatedWith(key) {
            case None           => Some(new StringBuilder(value))
            case Some(oldValue) => Some(oldValue.append(value))
          }
        )
    }
  loop(remaining = list, acc = Map.empty)
}

val data = List("ptxt"->"how","list"->"you doing","ptxt"->"whats up","ptxt"-> "this ","list"->"is ","list"->"cool")
mergeByKey(data)
// res: List[String] = List("howwhats upthis ", "you doingis cool")
```

---

Or a one liner using `groupMap`.
*(inspired on pme's answer)*

```
data.groupMap(_._1)(_._2).view.mapValues(_.mkString).valuesIterator.toList
```

Comment: Your output isn't the same as the expected `Seq("how you doing", "whats up", "this is cool")`

Comment: (though honestly I don't know how you'd expect to get that from this input anyway)

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Yeah, I am pretty sure the expected output is misleading _(probably a typo)_. Thus, I just focused on the description of the problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer since I don't have enough reputation points for adding a comment. just an improvment on Krzysztof Atłasik's answer. to compensate for the case where the Seq starts with a "list" you might want to add another case as:

```
  case (xs,("list", s)) if xs.isEmpty=>xs
```

So the final code could be something like:

```
val s = Seq("list"->"how ","list"->"you doing","ptxt"->"whats up","ptxt"-> "this ","list"->"is ","list"->"cool")

val r: Seq[String] = s.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
  case (xs,("list", s)) if xs.isEmpty=>xs
  case (xs, ("ptxt", s)) => s :: xs
  case (x :: xs, ("list", s)) => (x + s) :: xs
}.reverse
```

Comment: This is nice add on, but in this case I am losing the "how you doing"
the desired output should be:
Seq("how you doing", "whats up", "this is cool")
this will do the trick:
case (xs,("list1", s)) if xs.isEmpty=>s :: xs

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and Thanks for the upvote. Now  I can finally add comments :) . About the "how you doing" part, from what I understood you wanted to merge the "ptxt" wtih "list" that comes after it until the next "ptxt". So in this case since the first "ptxt" comes after the "list"->"how " and "list"->"you doing" so should'nt both of them be discarded?